# Ruby IDE for Ubuntu Linux 64bit

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, ide, 64-bit, ubuntu-11.04

I was wondering if there was a Ruby IDE for ubuntu linux 64 bit. I have checked around a bit and found Aptana studio but it will not actually install just launch from a folder. So any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried several (Aptana, redcar, etc.) and always go back to using gmate, which is a set of plugins for gedit.  It includes several themes like textmate and railscasts.

It allows you to extract partials, display the directory structure and class definitions in the side bar and comes with loads of autocomplete snippets for common tasks, such as:

typing end and pressing tab when editting an erb file results in:

```
<% end -%>
```

I also recommend the tabextend plugin which allows you to close all tabs at once, middle click to close a tab and close all except the tab in focus.

Installation instructions here: http://maketecheasier.com/transform-gedit-into-a-web-developer-ide/2010/12/29